# Do empty model group definitions in XSD change the defined valid XML language?

Tags: xsd

In [AUTOSAR_00048.xsd](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/19-11/AUTOSAR_MMOD_XMLSchema.zip) there are many model group definitions with a sequence with no particles, like this:

```
<xsd:group xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:AR="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0" name="AR-ELEMENT">
  <xsd:sequence/>
</xsd:group>
```

I don't know if a model group can be extended in some way. But there is definitely no extension of `AR-ELEMENT` in this XSD.

My question is whether such a "empty" group model changes the sets of XML instances specified by the XSD. Or whether such model group definitions could also be missing and the language determined by the XSD would still be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty model group can be deleted without changing the meaning of the XSD model in any way.

There is no extension mechanism for model groups. Sometimes a standards body provides an empty model group as a placeholder for user-defined elements. This ensures that user-defined elements are added in a defined place in the XSD. Not sure whether that is the reason for the empty model groups in your XSD though.